# React native GiftedChat change state loop

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I've been trying to use react-native-gifted-chat to make my chat app, but as soon as I try to render the component (even one that contains just GiftedChat) it ends up in a state change loop and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I've tried emptying the component to make it return just the `<GiftedChat />` component and it kept ending up in the loop.

I'm using it inside a stack navigator if it does make any difference.

**Also it's worth a mention, that when I replace GiftedChat with View the screen renders just fine.**

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if we don't know how you've written your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you. I was just about to explore the gifted chat and it gave me infinite loop which makes me have no idea what happened. And I also tried to rebuild my app from scratch...

However, I found it is just foxy. The solution is just copy paste the example code from gifted chat github to your file. Do not leave it only a `<GiftedChat />` in the file.

[React-native-gifted-chat Github](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat#example).